# Translate request to Angular 2 and Type Script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There is a Post request

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:32001/api/job/jobs-list-excel",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "9135e481-df69-b870-4f72-92873c1fd7de"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\"jobIds\": [2,3]}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I'm doing it in Angular 2, but she dont work, why? 
In the request, I need to transfer the list of Item IDs.
And in return, get the xls file, but I can not do it. I made a post request, but I can not translate it into an Angular

```
 public GetJobsListExcel(jobs: JobViewModel[]): Promise<Result> {
        var JobIds: number[] = [];
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        jobs.forEach(x => JobIds.push(x.JobId));

        return this.http.post(this.jobsUrl + "/jobs-list-excel",
            {
                jobIds: JobIds,
            },
            {
                headers: headers
            })
            .toPromise()  
            .then(response => response.json() as Result);
    }
```

Comment: send data as `JSON.stringify({jobIds: JobIds})` same as you are sending it in your post request above.

Comment: What is inside response in the last then ? Can you `console.log(response)` and report the result. Also put the reject handler and console.log() there too.  Change `.then(response => response.json() as Result);` to `.then(response => console.log(response), err => console.log(err));` and then you can report back. I don't see you to set the token in `headers` -> `"postman-token": "9135e481-df69-b870-4f72-92873c1fd7de"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';

    let body = JSON.stringify({ 'jobIds': '[2,3]' });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },{'cache-control':'no-cache'},{'postman-token':'9135e481-df69-b870-4f72-92873c1fd7de'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = 'http://localhost:32001/api/job/jobs-list-excel';

    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
                    .map(res =>  res.json().data)
                    .catch(this.handleError)
```